# iOS Objective-C Memory sufficient removal of elements (ARCs impact on child elements)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

When removing a `UIView` using `removeFromSuperview`, will **ARC** correctly handle the `dealloc` of the `UIView`'s child elements?

E.g:

```
UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:myView];

UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
[myLabel setText:@"Hey"];
[myView addSubview:myLabel];
```

in the event of `didReceiveMemoryWarning`:

```
[myView removeFromSuperview];
```

Will `[myView removeFromSuperview];` be sufficient enough to remove `myView`'s child element (`myLabel`), or should the child element be removed as well?

As a side question: Should `myView` be set to `nil` in addition to being removed from superview, or will **ARC** handle it?

Comment: If `myView` is a local variable as your have shown here then you don't need to set it to nil - it's reference will be removed as soon as it goes out of scope.  If it is a `strong` property or iVar then it needs to be explicitly set to `nil`.  Normally `weak` references are used with the parent view holding the only `strong` reference for this reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  An object's strong properties' are released when the object is released.  This will be true for a view's `subviews` array.  Since an array's elements are released when the array is released, those subviews will be released, too.  The code to do all of this is inserted by ARC.

Remember that releasing only decrements an object's reference count.  The object isn't freed until its reference count reaches zero.  This means that if there are other strong pointers to the subviews retained elsewhere, the subviews will remain.

So...

```
[someView removeFromSuperview];  // will free someView's subviews
```

but...

```
[someView addSubview:someSubview];
someObject.strongProperty = someSubview;

[someView removeFromSuperview];  // will free someView's subviews
// but not someSubview, which is now retained elsewhere
```